# Scope for single controller, multiple views

Tags: jsf, cdi, scopes

I have been studying new java 1.8 + CDI + WildFly And JSF 2.2.

I´ve read a lot about the scopes and still can´t figure out which scope should i use or what is the best practice to get a single controller to work with diferent views.

Can´t use the `@ViewScoped` because it works just for one view. 
`@SessionScoped` doesn´t look like the right path, and `@ConversationScope` looks like too much for what I´m looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Then use the [DeltaSpike @ViewAccessScoped](http://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/jsf.html#@ViewAccessScoped)

From their docs (emphasis mine)

> In case of conversations you have to un-scope beans manually (or they will be terminated automatically after a timeout). However, sometimes you need beans with a lifetime which is as long as needed and as short as possible - which are terminated automatically (as soon as possible). In such an use-case you can use this scope. **The simple rule is, as long as the bean is referenced by a page - the bean will be available for the next page (if it is used again the bean will be forwarded again)**. It is important that it is based on the view-id of a page (it is not based on the request) so, for example, Ajax requests do not trigger a cleanup if the request does not access all view-access scoped beans of the page. That’s also the reason for the name @ViewAccessScoped.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a defined entry point and exit point in your application, you can use JSF 2.2 `@FlowScope`

> **What is a Faces flow?**
>
> A collection of JSF views (and related artifacts) with explicitly
>   defined entry and exit points that have been assigned some application
>   specific meaning by the developer.  Usually the objects in a faces
>   flow   are designed to allow the user to accomplish a task that
>   requires   input over a number of different views.  The canonical
>   example of a   flow is an "order checkout" process where the user
>   enters in address,   payment, shipping information, etc., and then
>   submits the entire   result at the end, placing an order.

source: https://javaserverfaces-spec-public.java.net/nonav/proposals/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-730/proposal.txt